# How to return specified text if true in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dataframe that looks at the column 'Study Title' and returns a text category in a new column 'Categories' if the 'Study Title' column contains specific text in the string. For example, if the study title contains the text 'Child Care' or 'Head Start' then it will return a value if true in the new 'Categories' column with 'Child Care' for 'Child Care' and 'School Readiness' for 'Head Start', etc. How can I add multiple conditions with more values if true so that I have a list of strings to look for that returns a value I assign?

This is an example of what I would like the output to look like where the column 'Categories' returns the value 'Child Care' if the title contains the words 'Child Care'.

[image]

I have more conditions I want to include for other title considerations like 'School Readiness' for 'Head Start'. So far what I have only returns a true/false value based on the one condition for 'Child Care'.

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
df['Categories'] = df['Study Title'].str.contains(r'Child Care', na=True)
df
```

Copy-Paste CSV Sample

```
    
Study Title,URL,Funding Agency,Category
"American Indian and Alaska Native Head Start Family and Child Experiences Survey, 2015",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/36804,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
American Indian and Alaska Native Head Start Family and Child Experiences Survey 2019 (AIAN FACES 2019),https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/38028,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Carolina Abecedarian Project (ABC) and the Carolina Approach to Responsive Education (CARE), Age 21 Follow Up Study, 1993 - 2003",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/32262,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2009",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/32261,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2011",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/34390,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2012",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/34902,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2013",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/35482,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2014",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/36276,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
"Child Care and Development Fund (CCDF) Policies Database, 2015",https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/36581,United States Department of Health and Human Services. Administration for Children and Families. Office of Planning Research and Evaluation,
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe as copy-paste-able text. Can you clarify, what should happen if both terms show up in a Study Title?

Comment: To further clarify, if one of your target terms is in a Study Title, `Categories` should be `True` and `Category` should be a string corresponding to that target term?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do by providing a sample of the input dataframe and a second sample showing the desired output. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Also, provide the code you have written which attempts to solve this problem per the requirements of [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example")

Comment: @ddejohn I've included a copy-paste snip of the sample. If more than one term is found in the Study Title then return string 'Children'. I updated the columns for more clarity.

Comment: @itprorh66 I provided a sample of the input dataframe with the desired output. I provided the code at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is essentially a mapping, which a basic membership test is not suitable for. You need to define a mapping function:

```py
In [8]: def determine_category(title):
   ...:     if "Child Care" in title:
   ...:         return "Child"
   ...:     elif "Head Start" in title:
   ...:         return "School Readiness"
   ...:     return "no matching category"
   ...:

In [9]: df["Study Title"].apply(determine_category)
Out[9]:
0        School Readiness
1        School Readiness
2    no matching category
3                   Child
4                   Child
5                   Child
6                   Child
7                   Child
8                   Child
Name: Study Title, dtype: object
```